# Can't send email as Organization Wide Email Address in Apex action in a User Record Triggered Flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, apexactionfunction

I need to send an email that will pull data from multiple objects that are unrelated (meaning I can't use Email Alert).

I created a custom Apex Action for this that uses an Organization Wide Email Address to send an email containing the relevant information.

When I use this Apex action in any other flow type other than the Record Triggered Flow on the user object it works fine and sends out the email with the Organization Wide Email Address as the sender with the correct displayname.

However, when I use it in the User Record Triggered Flow It always changes the sender to the User's email that invoked the trigger (The person who creates a new user instead of the Organization wide email address).  So instead of sending as the OWEA it sends it as the current user and causes a *DMARC* Error.

Does anyone know why?

I have even tried to add it in a subflow that runs in system mode and then put the subflow in the user Record triggered flow but it still does the same thing.

Below Is My code

```
public without sharing class SendEmailFromTemplateFlow {
  @InvocableMethod(label='Welcome Email using template')
  public static list<Results> sendHTMLTemplateEmail(list<Requests> inputs) {
    list<Results> resultList = new List<Results>();
    //get the org wide email address to use in the email method
    OrgWideEmailAddress owea = [
      SELECT Id, DisplayName
      FROM OrgWideEmailAddress
      WHERE DisplayName = 'Support'
      LIMIT 1
    ];
//get email templates from input list
list<String> emailTemplateNameList = new List<String>();
for (Requests req : inputs) {
  String templateName = req.templateName;
  emailTemplateNameList.add(templateName);
}
list<EmailTemplate> templateList = new List<EmailTemplate>();
try {
  templateList = [
    SELECT Id, DeveloperName, Subject, Body, HtmlValue
    FROM EmailTemplate
    WHERE DeveloperName IN :emailTemplateNameList
  ];
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.debug(
    'There was an error trying to get the Email Templates.  The error was as follows: ' +
    e.getMessage()
  );
  Results result = new Results();
  result.successStatus = false;
  resultList.add(result);
  return resultList;
}

//send out the email for each request coming through
for (Requests req : inputs) {
  EmailTemplate emailTemplateToUse = new EmailTemplate();
  //Align the current request email template with the SOQL email template list to find the correct email template to use
  for (EmailTemplate emailTemp : templateList) {
    if (emailTemp.DeveloperName.equalsIgnoreCase(req.templateName)) {
      emailTemplateToUse = emailTemp;
    }
  }

  String htmlBody = emailTemplateToUse.HtmlValue;

  //Replace all of the String values being passed through from the flow
  for (String replacementInput : req.wordsToReplaceList) {
    //Get the original word that needs to be replaced
    String wordToReplace = replacementInput.substringBefore('=');
    String varForattedWordToReplace ='\\{!' + wordToReplace + '\\}';
    String wordToReplaceWith = replacementInput.substringAfter('='); 
    if (wordToReplaceWith != null) {
      htmlBody = htmlBody.replaceAll(varForattedWordToReplace, wordToReplaceWith);
      htmlBody = htmlBody.replaceAll(wordToReplace, wordToReplaceWith);
    }
  }

  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailToSend = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
  emailToSend.setTargetObjectId(req.userId);
  emailToSend.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.Id);
  emailToSend.setSubject(req.emailSubject);
  emailToSend.setSaveAsActivity(false);
  emailToSend.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
  //If there are any CC email addresses set that as well
  if (req.CCEmailAddressList != null) {
    if (req.CCEmailAddressList.size() > 0) {
      emailToSend.setCcAddresses(req.CCEmailAddressList);
    }
  }

  //send actual email to user
  try {
    list<Messaging.SendEmailResult> emailResults = Messaging.sendEmail(
      new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{ emailToSend }
    );
    Results result = new Results();
    result.successStatus = true;
    resultList.add(result);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.debug(
      'The email could not be sent due to the following error: ' +
      e.getMessage()
    );
    Results result = new Results();
    result.successStatus = false;
    resultList.add(result);
  }
}
return resultList;
```

}

Comment: does that OWEA include the user's Profile as an allowed profile to send from?

Comment: I didn't know thats something that one would need to consider.  I will check it out quickly and get back to you.  Thank you very much for the reply!

Comment: Yeah, the OWEA Includes all profiles.